# How the dielectric rigidity depends on the shape of material?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-detectors

[image]

A research article says that, "The conical shape improves the dielectric rigidity", but how I am not able to understand.

Comment: Could you give a link to that article?

Comment: Link of article: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900296011722